# Error "TypeError: Serial() takes no arguments" en Python (pySerial, Raspbian)

Tags: python, raspbian, pyserial

estoy intentando leer los bytes que entran mediante un usb (el cable que está enchufado en el usb es un conversor usb-serial232).

Yo no se mucho de python,y he estado buscando ayuda por internet hasta que me he encontrado con el siguiente código:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600)

while True:
    data = ser.readline()
    if data:
        print(data)
```

Cuando ví esto me dio buenas vibraciones, ya que la forma que tengo de leer el mbus es con una librería de Linux que utiliza el ttyISB0.

La 1era vez que lo ejecuté me pedía que instalase la librería 'serial'. Como estoy trabajando con PyCharm, con hacer Ctrl-Mayus-Intro se me instalaba sola.

Una vez instalé serial, me dio el error de 'Serial' (S mayúscula). Total, que lo instalé también.

Pero me sigue dando el siguiente error:

```
/root/PycharmProjects/prueba1/venv/bin/python /root/PycharmProjects/prueba1/file1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/prueba1/file1.py", line 2, in <module>
    ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600)
TypeError: Serial() takes no arguments

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Y ya no se que hacer, he estado mirando en internet, pero no hay nada sobre ese error.

//ACTUALIZACIÓN

He instalado el paquete pyserial y he puesto el siguiente código:

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', timeout=2, baudrate=115000, xonxoff=False, rtscts=False, dsrdtr=False)

ser.flushInput()
ser.flushOutput()

while True:
  data_raw = ser.readline()
  print(data_raw)
```

No me da error y me devuelve lo siguiente:

```
/home/pi/PycharmProjects/file3/file3.py
    b''
    b''
    b''
```

Tengo el M-Bus conectado con un conversor serial-usb, sé que funciona porque cuando ejecuto el sguiente comando en el Terminal, me devuelve la info

```
mbus-serial-request-data -b 2400 /dev/ttyUSB0 3
```

No sé como usarlo para que cuando le pida los datos, me lea los bytes que pasan por el usb.

Toda ayuda será bien recibida.
Un Saludo

Comment: El nombre de la librería que necesitas es ['pyserial'](https://pypi.org/project/pyserial/) no 'serial' o cualquier otra cosa...Me da que has instalado los paquetes equivocados...De hecho existe un paquete llamado [serial](https://pypi.org/project/serial/) en PyPi que nada tiene que ver con lo que buscas y que encima tiene conflictos de namespace con PySerial:https://bitbucket.org/davebelais/serial/issues/2/namespace-conflict. Si has instalado este paquete **desintalalo primero** y luego instala pyserial: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda @FJSevilla ahora no me da ningún error, pero me devuelve todo el rato el valor de b' ' , sigue sin mostrarme los bytes por pantalla

Comment: @javiertxu18 yo entiendo que la opción: `-b 2400` indica el baudrate, y en cambio en pyserial lo estableces en 115200 que podria causar el problema. Prueba cambiando a `ser = serial.Serial(..., baudrate=2400,  ...)`